# Replace the text in a file, but faster

Tags: c#, string, filestream

So I made a math problem program that basically reads one number from a text file (only number in that text file) and replaces it with a number+1 if number is not a solution.
Now the issue is, if I only add a text in the next row using

```
sw.WriteLine(text);
```

that makes the calculations really fast, doing 100k+ numbers in a few seconds, but it's just adding the number to the text file without deleting previous.

Alternatively I used

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("numbers.txt");
 foreach (string line in lines)
 {
      lines[0] = Convert.ToString(biginta);
 }                     
            File.WriteAllLines("numbers.txt", lines);
```

but that made my program run considerably slower.

Is there a way I can replace text in a .txt file by using already open filestream?

I'm new to c# so my whole program is basically a Frankenstein of a code.

Comment: problem is, when storing numbers as text, they take up a different number of bytes. If you replace "9" with "10", you need to rewrite the rest of the file to make room for 1 character.

Comment: Perhaps the question is: why are you storing it in a file? If you want to update a value like this frequently, then a file is probably not the storage option you're looking for.

Comment: It's a big math calculation that has to find the right number, and I'm using a file to store the next number needed to run because I turn off my pc overnight. Current number is at around 200 trillion

Comment: @ChuftiMeatball A simple flat text file is not the only format that can survive a machine restart. Lookup examples such as a database or persistent cache. Or perhaps restructure your files to avoid having to change a tiny bit in a large file.

Comment: Just `[BinaryWriter].Write([some string]); [BinaryWriter].BaseStream.Position = 0;`? Or something like this. If you really need to write this BigInteger each time you generate one (probably better write a buffer instead of a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using a file to store the next number needed to run because I turn off my pc overnight.

Honestly the quickest solutiion to this is the following: Read the file once, do *several* (like 100) calculations without saving and then store the current number back into the file.
Tune the interval so that you store the current state once every 5 seconds or so.

That gives you still a good starting point (at most 5 seconds lost work) but also reduces disk IO to the point where it won't slow down the calculation any more.